# Parse time with strptime using Time.zone

Tags: ruby, datetime, activesupport

I am trying to parse a datetime with Time class in Ruby 2.0. I can't figure out how to parse date and get it in a specified timezone. I have used `Time.zone.parse` to parse a date where I first call `Time.zone` and set it to a specified timezone. In the below example, I set the zone but it does not effect `strptime`, I have tried doing `Time.zone.parse(date)` but I can't get it parse a date like the one below.

```
Time.zone = "Central Time (US & Canada)"
#=> "Central Time (US & Canada)"
irb(main):086:0> Time.strptime("08/26/2013 03:30 PM","%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
#=> 2013-08-26 15:30:00 -0400
```

Comment: As far as I know there is no `zone=` class method for `Time`. Doesn't this fail with a `NoMethodError`?

Comment: @Borodin There’s not in Ruby, but ActiveSupport adds one in.

Answer (score 8):

[`Time.zone`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-c-zone) isn’t a part of Ruby, it’s a part of [ActiveSupport](https://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport) (which is included with Rails). As such, [`strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-strptime) does not know about `Time.zone` at all. You can, however, convert a normal Ruby Time into an [ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html) using [`in_time_zone`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-in_time_zone), which uses `Time.zone`’s value by default:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/time'
Time.zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

time = Time.strptime('08/26/2013 03:30 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p')
#=> 2013-08-26 15:30:00 -0400
time.in_time_zone
#=> Mon, 26 Aug 2013 14:30:00 CDT -05:00
```

Comment: @muistooshort Yea… If there’s one thing I wish every language had it’s a good & complete standard Date/Time library. (Of course, Ruby’s is far from the worst.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking at Ruby2.0, you may find the time lib useful:

```rb
require 'time'
time.zone # return your current time zone

a = Time.strptime("08/26/2013 03:30 PM","%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
# => 2013-08-26 15:30:00 +1000
a.utc  # Convert to UTC
a.local # Convert back to local
# Or you can add/subtract the offset for the specific time zone you want:
a - 10*3600 which gives UTC time too
```

Answer (score 1):

`strptime` gets its parameters from the time string. As such, the time string must contain time zone information.

If you are parsing time strings in a specific time zone, but the time strings that you receive do not have it embedded - then you can add time zone information before passing the time string to `srtptime`, and asking `strptime` to parse the time zone offset using `%z` or name using `%Z`.

In a nutshell, if you have a time string `08/26/2013 03:30 PM` and you want it parsed in the `UTC` time zone, you would have:

```
str = '08/26/2013 03:30 PM'
Time.strptime("#{str} UTC}", "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p %Z")
```