# Convert timestamp string without timezone to Time object in known timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some timestamp strings (e.g. "23/06/2021 13:46") that I know to be in the UK local time (either GMT or BST depending on time of year), but they have no timezone indication as part of the string.

Within rails what is a sensible way to turn them into Time objects in the correct timezone?

I can do it in a really roundabout way:

```
time_string = "23/06/2021 13:46"
base_time = Time.parse(time_string)

Time.use_zone("Europe/London") do
  Time.zone.now.change(year: base_time.year, month: base_time.month, day: base_time.day, hour: base_time.hour, min: base_time.min, sec: base_time.sec)
end

=> Wed, 23 Jun 2021 13:46:00 BST +01:00
```

But there must be a better way!

I have read loads of different sources and all seem to be about how to convert an existing time object into a different timezone, or cast a Time object to a string.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse time with strptime using Time.zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138450/parse-time-with-strptime-using-time-zone)

Comment: See the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138450/parse-time-with-strptime-using-time-zone

Comment: I don't believe these work, Time.strptime doesn't seem to respect Time.zone, it still takes system timezone. From my mac with system time overridden.

Time.zone = "Europe/London"
Time.strptime("08/26/2013 03:30 PM","%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
=> 2013-08-26 15:30:00 +0600

Comment: Look at the most upvoted answer. You have to use `in_time_zone` to get ActiveSupport's time zone.

Comment: Yep I see, but I still don't think it does quite what I'm after. I have a timestamp string, which I know to be UK time, and I want to use to generate a time object in the UK timezone for the date in the string. 

So as inputs "2021-7-21 09:45" should give me a Time object for 9:45 am BST (+01:00), and "2021-1-21 09:45" should give me a time object for 9:45 am GMT (+00:00).

strftime will parse it as system time, which is not necessarily the right timezone, and then I can turn it into a different timezone, but the base point is still wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making use of a gem called "Time of Day", it will take a string and give you a time of day object, you can then convert that to local time in your current `Time.zone` on any date you chose:

```
Time.zone = "Europe/London"

time_string = "23/06/2021 13:46"
parts = time_string.split(" ")

date = Date.parse(parts[0])
tod = Tod::TimeOfDay.parse(parts[1])

tod.on date   # => Wed, 23 Jun 2021 13:46:00 BST +01:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [in_time_zone](https://apidock.com/rails/DateTime/in_time_zone) method to convert a timestamp to your server's time zone:

```
time_string = "23/06/2021 13:46"
base_time = Time.parse(time_string)
new_time = base_time.in_time_zone
```

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm after, Time.parse doesn't seem to respect Time.zone, it follows system time.

On my mac with system time overriden to +06:00.
Time.zone = "Europe/London"
Time.parse(time_string)
=> 2021-08-08 10:15:36 +0600

Comment: Right that is why you need to tag on the `in_time_zone` method: `Time.parse(time_string).in_time_zone`.

Comment: Still not right I'm afraid. We're going round in circles, but the time string is a UK time string, so in June that's +01:00, if I run the above code on a server where system time is UTC, I get "Wed, 23 Jun 2021 13:46:00.000000000 UTC +00:00", which is wrong, it should be 12:46 UTC, not 13:46 UTC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Time.find_zone](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-c-find_zone-21) method.

```
Time.find_zone("UTC").parse("23/06/2021 13:46")
# => Wed, 23 Jun 2021 13:46:00.000000000 UTC +00:00
```

`Time.find_zone` returns an `ActiveSupport::TimeZone` instance which provides a `parse` method that parses the string on that timezone.